# TextBlock shown without text in expanded WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using C# with WPF, to draw some graphics and texts into a WPF Canvas.
For adding texts to the canvas I use a TextBlock and this works fine when I don't change the size of the Canvas.
When I extend the width of the canvas, sometimes the text is not drawn (from the x-position where I extended the canvas). The text is there, because I can see the text background (and also a strikethrough which I added for testing).
When I change the length of the text and/or set the TextBlock length in code, the behavior changes. Meaning with some changes the text is shown.
The graphics are shown just fine in all circumstances.

I've tried to make sure the Width and ActualWidth of the Canvas are correct before I draw the texts.

I use this code to draw the text onto the Canvas:

```
private void drawHeartrate(string hr, double xHr)
{
    TextBlock hrTextBlock = new TextBlock();
    hrTextBlock.Text = hr;
    hrTextBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    hrTextBlock.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
    hrTextBlock.Background = Brushes.Yellow;

    hrTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Soho Gothic Pro");
    hrTextBlock.FontSize = 14;
    Canvas.SetLeft(hrTextBlock, xHr);
    Canvas.SetTop(hrTextBlock, -2);
    CnvsEcg.Children.Add(hrTextBlock);
}
```

The screen where the texts is not displayed anymore looks like this (from the above code):
[Screenshot of problem text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpTil.png)

Comment: Not sure how `Striketrhough` works for spaces (non printable characters?). Could it be that `hr` contains many spaces for some calls?

Comment: That's why I used Strikethrough ;-) I've also tested with static text (like "ABC"), with the same effect. So the problem is not in spaces or non-printable characters.

Comment: I doubt there is something wrong with wpf drawing or canvas control itself, must be something in your code. Can you create new solution with small xaml and copy this method there. If problem appears you have [mcve] to share.

Comment: When I make a simple Canvas project it seems to work. Indeed a lot of stuff is going on in the code, will be hard to implement this in a small piece of code. Can there be any explanation why a hard-coded text is not shown, but the strikethrough is visible?

Comment: I have some more information: When I use a longer static text "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", I can see that on the point the text is disappearing the text is stuck on it's x-position. So the last correct text is the complete text. The next text is like "EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", then the next text is like "PQRSTUVWXYZ" and the last visible text is like "YZ". Where the last 3 values have there letters on the same x-position. But still the background and strikethrough are correct. Could this be a .NET bug?

Comment: Made a workaround! Really seemed like a bug in the framework. Decided to just draw texts in bitmaps and place these bitmaps on the canvas. So for me it's solved. Thanks for the input